# How to run cscope from any directory?

Tags: linux, bash, vim, fedora, cscope

I set up cscope as explained in this [tutorial](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/large_projects.html). I do not want to regenerate my database on every invocation of cscope and hence I start it `cscope -d`. But the problem is, I need to run this command from the directory where my DB, cscope.out resides. I keep shuffling across directories and I want the flexibility to start cscope from anywhere. I tried putting `CSCOPE_DB=~/cscope/cscope.out; export CSCOPE_DB` in my .bash_profile/.bashrc to no avail. I also have `export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim` in my bash profile files and as such can invoke cscope from within vim from any directory but not the standalone cscope! It always throws the error

```
cscope: cannot open file cscope.out
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. Assuming my cscope DB is in `~/cscope`, I `cd` into this directory, launch `cscope` and go back to the directory I came from. Like so-

```
cd ~/cscope && cscope -d && cd - > /dev/null
```

Effectively, I'm able to launch `cscope` from any directory( and also stay in the same directory after `cscope` exits ). I've aliased the above command and just typing `cs` does the trick